# How do I find/excute Python Interactive Mode in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm unable to find/execute the interactive mode in Visual Studio Code. What are the step-by-step instructions for it?

- Menu *View* → *Other Windows* →  Interactive menu commands). *[Work with the Python Interactive window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/python-interactive-repl-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)*

I don't have "Other windows".

Is there something I need to install?

Comment: Terminal > New Terminal then `python` or `python3` at the cmd prompt

Comment: Be aware that Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are different.

Answer (score 11):

If you type `# %%` in your Visual Studio Code editor while editing a .py file, then an interactive cell is created and it can be evaluated.

The nice part of this is that # denotes a comment in a .py file, so you can save and run your code as a script.

Comment: That's amazing! I never knew you could run cells like that

Comment: make sure you have the interactive kernel package installed. Otherwise this would not work.

Answer (score 7):

If you have the Python extension, you can use the Python Interactive feature (this is a [IPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython)/[Jupyter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Jupyter#Jupyter_Notebook) console, which can run parts of your code as 'cells', i.e., snippets of code executed in one go).

This article writes about the interactive window and many more possibilities of using Jupyter in Visual Studio Code: *[Python Interactive window](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py)*

#### Best option

When editing Python code, select something and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will open the interactive window and run your selection as a single cell.

I have personally been annoyed many times by accidentally pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd> on a line of code which (alone) would be a syntax error. Then, one day I decided to start using this feature consciously.

#### Terminal fallback

Press: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

This opens a system shell ([Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29), or on Windows: [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell) or [cmd.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe)).

Run `python`, or `ipython` if you have it (`pip install ipython`), and use the interactive window. In the terminal, you can also execute your script, by typing `python myscript.py arguments`.

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio Code, you can enter the Python interactive window in the following places:

### Option 1

<kbd>F1</kbd> → <kbd>Python: Create Python Interactive Window</kbd>

This is the [Python interactive](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py#_python-interactive-window) window that comes with Visual Studio Code.
You can enter the interactive window without inputting instructions.
Please use "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>" to execute the code:

[image: option1_screenshot]

### Option 2

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

This is the cmd window that comes with the Visual Studio Code integration computer.
We need to enter the command "`python`" to enter the Python interactive window:

[image: option2_screenshot]

### PS

For more information about using Python in `Visual Studio Code`, you can refer to the official Visual Studio Code documentation: [Python in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial).

Comment: I think they changed how all of that works since this answer was given. there is no `Create Python Interactive Window` anymore. `shift+enter` always works, but now they also have jupyter notebook cells with `# %%`