# Test Python code interactively in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a question about python in VS Code.
In IDE spyder I can define a function and test it in the terminal. For example:

```
def test(a):
    return a + 1
```

If I write in terminal `test(4)` it will return 5. How can I make this work in VS Code? The same example in VS Code returns this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find/excute Python Interactive Mode in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64730660/how-do-i-find-excute-python-interactive-mode-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: VS-Code makes it super easy to run a Jupyter Notebook, personally I'd just start there~

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to solve this problem:

1.creat a python file and run this file:

[image]

[image]

2. Run code in terminal

[image]

Comment: OP asked for interactive mode in VSCode. Neither of your options answer that question